# jquery UI combobox with a select onchange event - the onchange doesn't fire

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

http://jsfiddle.net/KJSvs/

I am using [jQuery UI combobox](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) with some select boxes like the one in the jsfiddle example above. The onchange attributes are populated dynamically. How do I get combobox to fire the original onchange event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are after or not?

http://jsfiddle.net/KJSvs/1/

Comment: For future Googlers, I also added the onchange trigger call to the select, so that users don't have to wait until they blur the field to see the resulting UI changes. http://jsfiddle.net/KJSvs/2/